# PHP setcookie and one-part domain name

Tags: php, setcookie

I have some doubts concerning `domain` parameter of `setcookie` function. Having the following code:

setcookie.php:

```
setcookie("cook_1", "c1", time()+3600, "", "home_domain.com");
setcookie("cook_2", "c2", time()+3600, "", "sub.home_domain.com");
```

Everythig works as expected - requesting `http:\\home_domain.com\setcookie.php` makes `cook_1` and available for further `http:\\sub2.home_domain.com\getcookie.php` request

BUT

when i shorten the main domain name to just one-part like so:

```
setcookie("cook_1", "c1", time()+3600, "", "home_domain");
setcookie("cook_2", "c2", time()+3600, "", "sub.home_domain");
```

the `cook_1` cookie **isn't** available for further http:\sub2.home_domain\getcookie.php`.

Why does such shortening the domain name makes such a difference?